# unable to change package name in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to rename my app package because by mistake I set it as com.example.tanmayagarwalquix , so i want to change that "example" part to "tanbruh" and "tanmayagarwalquix" to "tanmayagarwalquiz" , so i right clicked on "example" and then clicked on refractor then rename but this time its showing some strange warning (unlike it always shows rename package or rename directory options) and when I click on rename all then tried typing tanbruh but android studio get stucked, i had tried many times this same issue occuring, i had tried changing from manifest , and build.gradle also still issue occurs, Has anyone encountered this and is able to help me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

and when i clicked on rename all and change "example" to "tanbruh", then android studio stucked and nothing happened :-

[image]

this question is different from suggested question because this is the easiest way to edit package name unlike copy pasting to a new package and this way of changing package name always works but i don't know why this time its not working, please help :)

Comment: Probably changing the applicationId might be sufficient, btw, it's not stuck, it's processing a lot of different files from your project. In huge code bases it may take up to 10 minutes (I had this experience on a 7700HQ, 16 GB of RAM) It looks frozen but everything's fine, give it some time and grab a cup of coffee

Comment: sir its a small project , and I waited for 1 hour also and android studio was completely stucked, secondly only changing applicationId wasn't sufficient as it was throwing errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename package in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio)

Comment: nopes @hfontanez

Comment: @TanmayAgarwal what is different? It sounds like the same problem to me. You may want to include in your post why the solution in that link does not work. Trust me, you will want to do this your question will be closed. I know this from recent personal experience. The more information on this post as to what have you tried the better.

Comment: actually sir issue is, this is the simplest method when we change package name from here and i always do from here but this time i am getting these new options, so i want help, its not about my question, its easiest method to change package name which always works and this time not working so i was needing help.

Comment: "I waited for 1 hour also and android studio was completely stucked [sic]" This may sound silly but, have you tried rebooting your computer?

Comment: sir i tried everything and still the issue occurs

Comment: I have experienced similar issues with Eclipse in my home computer. The SSD is old (2013) and every once in a while Eclipse hangs while doing the simplest of things (i.e. renaming a variable). No matter how long I wait for, I have to ultimately kill the task. When I restart Eclipse, the changes are not done. Then, when I least expect it, I can do the same tasks without issues. I am convinced this a problem with my system, and not with Eclipse. Perhaps your problem is similar to mine. You can try reinstalling Android Studio. You have nothing to lose but a little bit of time.

Comment: Maybe one of your dependencies has a package starting with `com.example` so it is telling you it cannot change those. Try going into one of your classes and renaming the package from the `package` name of the file and see if it gives you the option to change other files in the same package to the new one. This would allow you to change the complete package address, not the upper level `com.example` package, so it shouldn't have this conflict.

Comment: okay let me check that @Tenfour04

Comment: i tried but now also same issue @Tenfour04